# Events within email to update calendar

Tags: google-schemas

I am new to this and I am trying to provide a service to my tennis players where they can go on website, fill up a form for reserving the court. The form will send an email with time and place when they want to play. Upon confirmation, that should update the calendar. I tried various scenarios provided, but it did not work. I am not sure what am I missing. I just send en email to myself as follows:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context":              "http://schema.org",
  "@type":                 "EventReservation",
  "reservationNumber":     "IO12345",
  "underName": {
    "@type":               "Person",
    "name":                "John Smith"
  },
  "reservationFor": {
    "@type":               "Event",
    "name":                "Google I/O 2013",
    "startDate":           "2017-08-30T08:30:00-08:00",
    "location": {
      "@type":             "Place",
      "name":              "Moscone Center",
      "address": {
        "@type":           "PostalAddress",
        "streetAddress":   "800 Howard St.",
        "addressLocality": "San Francisco",
        "addressRegion":   "CA",
        "postalCode":      "94103",
        "addressCountry":  "US"
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
<p>
  Dear John, thanks for booking your Google I/O ticket with us.
</p>
<p>
  BOOKING DETAILS<br/>
  Reservation number: IO12345<br/>
  Order for: John Smith<br/>
  Event: Google I/O 2013<br/>
  Start time: May 15th 2013 8:00am PST<br/>
  Venue: Moscone Center, 800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103<br/>
</p>


</body>

</html>
```

but I see it just a text as above.
thanks in advance,
Hagop

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a property : `reservationStatus` that is required. I've used the [Basic event reminder without a ticket](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/event-reservation#basic_event_reminder_without_a_ticket) JSON-LD:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "EventReservation",
  "reservationNumber": "E123456789",
  "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
  "underName": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "John Smith"
  },
  "reservationFor": {
    "@type": "Event",
    "name": "Foo Fighters Concert",
    "startDate": "2017-09-06T11:30:00-12:30",
    "location": {
      "@type": "Place",
      "name": "AT&T Park",
      "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "streetAddress": "24 Willie Mays Plaza",
        "addressLocality": "San Francisco",
        "addressRegion": "CA",
        "postalCode": "94107",
        "addressCountry": "US"
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      An event was reserved.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the result:

[image]

I've tried your code and added the `reservationStatus` and it worked. You can test your schemas using [Email Markup Tester](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/).

Hope this helps.